# Regex matching begining and middle of string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Here are two API responses:

```
error|38sax3z|Invalid Zip/State combination|0

declined|38sax3z|We were unable to place your lead at this time|0
```

This is what I used as regex for errors:

```
error\|[0-9A-z]+\|(?<Value>[^|]*)
```

But the second response is an error also, now I need the first part and third, second is dynamic value and I want to ignore it.

Can anyone assist with regex that will pull first and third parts only?

Comment: Something like that? [`(error|declined)\|[0-9A-z]+\|([^|]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/LjKEiH/1)

Comment: Try `(?m)^(?<Type>error|declined)\|[^|]*\|(?<Value>[^|]*)`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, here is one:

```
^(.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)\|
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string, then `.*?` matches anything in a non-greedy way which means that because we have `\|` following, it will match up to the following pipe.